# Provide system properties at runtime when building native image in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, spring-boot-maven-plugin, graalvm-native-image

I am upgrading an existing project to Spring Boot 3 to run as a native image. My application requires a custom trust store to connect to OpenLDAP, earlier I used to create a uber jar and provide the truststore path as system arguments when running the jar as shown below.

```
java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/ladu/Downloads/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

To build a native executable, I need to compile using a native image plugin (org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin). With native:compile phase, I have added the system properties but it doesn't seem to work as when I run the executable, I get an error indicating certificates are not present.

```
./mvnw -Pnative native:compile -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/ladu/Downloads/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

How do I provide the system properties at runtime, is it in the build phase like above but with some other syntax, or when running the executable but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to provide to native image on **runtime** explained like below

> If, on the other hand, you run the executable with app -Dfoo=bar, it will display foo in the list of properties because you specified it at executable runtime.

> In other words:

> Passing -D= as an argument to native-image affects properties seen at executable build time.
> Passing -D= as an argument to a native executable affects properties seen at executable runtime.

So if you run the native image like "**/app/demo -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/ladu/Downloads/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit**" it should work.

Check [this page](https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/native-image/Properties/) for more details. And graalvm supports javax.net.ssl truststore

> Run-time Options

> The certificate file can also be changed dynamically at run time via setting the javax.net.ssl.trustStore* system properties.

> If any of the following system properties are set during the image execution, native-image also requires javax.net.ssl.trustStore to be set, and for it to point to an accessible certificate file:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
```

For full documentation please check [here](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/CertificateManagement/)